# Do you know someone who has written a microROS agent for the OpenCr board?

Tags: microcontroller, ros2, ros-humble

We are using the turtlebot3 hardware components in our group. Now we want to implement our own tech stack. For this we want to build a micro ros agent on top of the opencr firmware - foxy devel branch. It would really help if someone had an example I could look at for this. Has anyone ever tried to build an opencr micro ros agent before and could show me their approach?

Comment: please ask about the problem, not about people's accomplishments

Comment: please describe what you are trying to accomplish, what you tried, how your attempt failed, and ask a focused answerable question

Comment: The exact question is a yes/no question, but it has no technical answer. What is the exact problem with the current software stack?

Comment: I would recommend looking at Github for this kind of thing, and focusing on the hardware you'd be writing the firmware for. OpenCR is on an STM32 chip, so I searched on Github for 'microros stm32', and I got plenty of results.